# What's the max length a cursorMark can have?

Tags: solr, lucene

As the title says I'd like to know the maximum length the `cursorMark` can have that I receive from Solr.

It would also be nice to get some info about chars that can be in it. But just the max length would already be nice. Does it even have one or can it theoretically grow without a limit?

Answer (score 2):

**Regarding the Set of Characters:**

Looking at the Solr [`CursorMark`](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/CursorMark.java#L263) source code, we can see that the representation of the cursor mark is a Base64 encoded String.

The specific implementation of Base64 used here is in Solr's [`Base64`](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/d3f4b21deb0056098e9e888a6b9d72e0bf2d0834/solr/solrj/src/java/org/apache/solr/common/util/Base64.java#L30) utility class. Here we can see their character set is:

```
private static final char intToBase64[] = {
      'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
      'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
      'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
      'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
      '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/'
};
```

There may also be `=` symbols if strings are padded. But I don't recall seeing those.

**Regarding the Length:**

The size will vary depending on the specific data being encoded (sufficient to identify a sort spec/position).

So, based on that, I only have anecdotal observation, which is that the order of magnitude is bytes, not kilobytes.

*Final note: This is all behind-the-scenes stuff - and, as such, may be subject to change without warning.*